# Cannot Display 2 Instances of my custom SurfaceView

Tags: android, tabs, surfaceview

I've created my own custom SurfaceView which works fine on its own but when I try putting two onto separate tabs in a [TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html) only one is ever shown regardless of which tab is selected, and it is always the SurfaceView which is first drawn when the app starts.

To illustrate the problem I have created sample code which can be compiled to display to problem.

The SurfaceView below, called SurfaceViewCircle simply creates a bitmap, draws a blue circle as default and then displays it. There is a public method, changeColour(), which will change the circle colour in the bitmap.

Secondly, I create an XML layout which simply contains a single instance of SurfaceViewCircle.

In the Activity class, I create a TabWidget and host etc. I then inflate the above XML twice but in one instance I change the colour of the SurfaceViewCircle to red. Once the application runs, no matter what tab I select, the red circle is ALWAYS shown EXCEPT for a brief instance when the app exits and the blue circle is displayed.

Can anyone point out if I have missed out a step when using SurfaceView?

This is the Activity code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity  {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private TabHost mTabHost;
private Context mTabHostContext;
private View surfaceView1, surfaceView2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /*
     * Setup tabs
     */
    setContentView(R.layout.maintabs);
        setupTabHost(); //Prepares the TabHost from code rather than XML;
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider); //Sets a thin dividing line
    mTabHostContext = mTabHost.getContext();
    surfaceView1 = LayoutInflater.from(mTabHostContext).inflate(R.layout.surfaceviewindependent, null);
    SurfaceViewCircle s = (SurfaceViewCircle)surfaceView1.findViewById(R.id.circle1);
    /*
     * Change the colour to red
     */
    s.changeColour(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_square));

    /*
     * Create a second layout containing SurfaceViewCircle but leave circle as default blue.
     */
    surfaceView2 = LayoutInflater.from(mTabHostContext).inflate(R.layout.surfaceviewindependent, null);
    setupTab(surfaceView1,"SurfaceView1");
    setupTab(surfaceView2,"SurfaceView2");


}

private void setupTabHost() {
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
}

private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag); // This creates a view to be used in the TAB only

    /* this creates the tab content AND applies the TAB created in the previous step in one go */
    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {return view;}
    });
    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);

}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);

    return view;
}   
}
```

This is my custom SurfaceView:

```
public class SurfaceViewCircle extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private Paint paint, circlePaint;
private Bitmap bitmap = null;
private int w;
private int h;
private int colour = 0;
private Resources r = null;
private _Thread t = null;
private boolean surfaceIsCreated;

public SurfaceViewCircle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initialise();
}

public SurfaceViewCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialise();
}

public SurfaceViewCircle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    initialise();
}

private void initialise(){
    r = getResources();
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    colour = R.color.blue_square;
    circlePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    circlePaint.setColor(r.getColor(colour));
    circlePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(0.02f);
    t = new _Thread(getHolder());


}

public void changeColour(int colour){
    circlePaint.setColor(colour);
    if (surfaceIsCreated){
        createBitmap();
    }
    synchronized (t){
        t.notify();
    }
}

private Bitmap createBitmap(){
    Bitmap b = null;
    b = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    c.scale((float)w, (float)w);        //Scales the background for whatever pixel size
    c.drawCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, circlePaint);
    //c.drawColor(r.getColor(colour));
    return b;
}

public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    int width = measure(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = measure(heightMeasureSpec);

    int d = Math.min(width, height);
    setMeasuredDimension(d,d);
}

private int measure(int measureSpec) {
    int result = 0;
    // Decode the measurement specifications
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    return specSize;
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH){
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);
    //synchronized (this){
        this.w = Math.min(w, h);
        this.h = w;
    //}
    Bitmap b = createBitmap();

        bitmap = b;

    Log.i("Square", "onSizeChanged() called.");


}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i("Panel", "surfaceCreated() called.");
    t.setRunning(true);
    t.start();
    surfaceIsCreated = true;

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i("Square", "surfaceDestroyed() called.");

    surfaceIsCreated = false;
    boolean retry = true;
    synchronized (t){
        t.setRunning(false);
        t.notify();
    }
    while (retry) {
        try {
            t.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // we will try it again and again...
        }
    }

}

private class _Thread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private boolean _run = false;

    public _Thread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c = null;
        while (_run){
            try {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                    synchronized(bitmap){
                        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
            synchronized(this){
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The maintabs.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />
            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the surfaceviewindependent.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
<uk.co.androidcontrols.gauges.SurfaceViewCircle
android:id="@+id/circle1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_margin="1dip">
</uk.co.androidcontrols.gauges.SurfaceViewCircle>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also noted that someone else has had a similar problem [here.](http://androidforums.com/application-development/225216-tabbed-surfaceviews-possible.html)

Apologies for the poor formatting but the code editor is nigh on impossible to use for large code quotes!

**Additional Info**

I tried using the `setVisibility()'` in `onvisibilityChanged()` but it eventually results in an exception:

```
protected void onVisibilityChanged(View changedView, int visibility){
    super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
    changedView.setVisibility(visibility);
    Log.i("SurfaceViewCircle", "onVisibilityChanged() called.");
}

java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
```

It appears calling `changedView.setvisibility()` destroys the surface each time.

Comment: on your setupTab you are only creating one as I see it, try checking this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5034063/1084764

Comment: Thanks Raykud. Will check that out and report back a little later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what I want to do with SurfaceView is not recommended: [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7d08a124a2e48bb3)

Answer (score 4):

I built a test project based on your code and surprisingly spent almost a couple of hours fiddling about with it. I'll quickly blurt out my findings now as I ought to hit the sack!

First of all, you're most definitely creating two tabs, with each tab having a separate instance of your custom `SurfaceView`. That's fine.

Now when the `Activity` first starts up and the first tab is shown, only the first `SurfaceView` is initialised and has `surfaceCreated()` called, at which point its `Thread` runs.

When the second tab is selected, the second `SurfaceView` that the `createTabContent()` callback supplies for it is then initialised just as the first one was. From then on from this point, until teardown of the `Activity`, *both* `SurfaceView`s remain in their valid surface state. Toggling between tabs never invokes `surfaceDestroyed()` on either `SurfaceView`, and so `SurfaceCreated()` is never invoked again either. Neither is 'onMeasure()' invoked again after first creation. Therefore, this tells me that both `SurfaceView`s remain in the overall `View` hierarchy. Both `SurfaceViews`' `Thread`s are running and, if you didn't have the `wait()` in there, both would be continuously trying to render to video memory.

As you know, a `SurfaceView` is very unique in how it sits (or rather, doesn't sit) within the `View` hierarchy. What seems to be happening here is that the first `SurfaceView` to be created is the one whose output is seen on video memory, regardless of tab selection.

One thing I first tried was to have the second `SurfaceView` significantly smaller than the first, with a proportionally smaller circle within. When switching from the first tab (larger `SurfaceView` with large red circle) to the second tab (smaller `SurfaceView` with smaller blue circle), I could see that the size of the visible `SurfaceView` reduced correctly as if the second `SurfaceView` was becoming visible, but rather than its smaller blue circle being visible, I had just a large portion of the first `SurfaceView`'s large red circle punching through, but cropped by the smaller size of the second `SurfaceView`.

What I ended up playing with were the following two methods calls:

```
((SurfaceView)surfaceView1.findViewById(R.id.circle1)).setVisibility(View.GONE);

((SurfaceView)view.findViewById(R.id.circle1)).bringToFront();
```

The latter, `bringToFront()`, didn't seem to achieve anything. But using the `setVisibility(View.GONE)` call on the *first* `SurfaceView` just as the *second* `SurfaceView`'s tab has been selected then had it nicely switching from a red circle to a blue circle.

What I think you therefore need to try doing is looking for a suitable `TabHost` API callback method to override which will be called `every` time a tab is selected (perhaps using `TabHost.OnTabChangeListener`) and use that as a place to call `setVisibility()` as appropriate on all of the `SurfaceView`s to control which one appears on top.

Comment: Thanks Trevor! I had to get some sleep too after posting my question and now I have to get to work! I'll take a good look through your answer later on.

Comment: Trevor: A few things to note. If you override the onVisibilityChanged() method you'll see that this does get called as the tab selection is changed. However I realise as I write this, in my actual 'production' code (not shown here) I do NOT call through to the super method... although in the example above I have not over-ridden this method. Also if you add a third tab to the above example which contains a standard Android button then switching between Button and surfaceview is OK but again not between surfaceviews. I might look at the source for the View class.

Comment: Also I did try calling the setVisibility() method but ran into some problems but I can possibly re-investigat ethis method again.

Comment: When I replicated the project, I also added a further two tabs to make four; the latter two contained simple TextViews. As you say, it would switch between those ordinary components just fine but the problem remained between the SurfaceViews. setVisibility() did seem to do the trick in a short simple test that I did, although I didn't have time to test a full fix.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I'll give your suggestion a go a little later on. There isn't something quite right though with the way SurfaceView works or the documentation isn't making it clear that subclasses of SurfaceView should handle their own visibility setting? I mean standard Android View classes e.g. Button handle visibility changes OK so why can't surfaceView? Would be nice to clarify this with someone from the Android development team.

Comment: Trevor: How/where did you put the setVisibility() call? I just get an exception the second time a tab is selected.